# Custom listview adapter OnRelease Event

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using a custom listview adapter. And i need a code inside adapter when the row is been pressed to making color Green and when it is been released to get back in white.

Here is an example

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {


        DataViewHolder holder = null;
        Button ExtraBtn;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);
            holder = new DataViewHolder();

            ExtraBtn = convertView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);
            ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) => {

  convertView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
            };
```

But i cant find a code to make my row white again when i'm not touch it.
Actually i need to make it  green  as long as it is pressed.

Comment: Find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784514/capture-button-release-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture button release in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784514/capture-button-release-in-android)

Comment: Or if there is a way to make it throug my xml

Comment: Hi, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50173742/8632294), download the demo on github.